# Title custom post type ACF

Tags: php, wordpress, advanced-custom-fields

so I have this custom post type made in my functions.php in Wordpress
I have my field group from Advanced custom fields linked to it

what I have for code for the Custom post type is

```
function init_members() {
$labels = array(
    'name'               => 'Leden',
    'singular_name'      => 'Lid',
    'menu_name'          => 'Leden',
    'name_admin_bar'     => 'Lid',
    'add_new'            => 'Nieuw lid',
    'add_new_item'       => 'Nieuw lid',
    'new_item'           => 'Nieuw lid',
    'edit_item'          => 'Bewerk lid',
    'all_items'          => 'Alle leden',
    'search_items'       => 'zoek leden',
    'not_found'          => 'Geen leden gevonden',
    'not_found_in_trash' => 'Geen leden gevonden in de prullenbak'
);

$args = array(
    'labels' => $labels,
    'public' => true,
    'exclude_from_search' => true,
    'rewrite' => array('slug' => 'lid'),
    'has_archive' => false,
    'supports' => array(''),
    'show_in_rest' => true,
    'menu_icon' => 'dashicons-groups'

);
register_post_type('members', $args);
}
add_action('init', 'init_members');
```

and this code is for what u see in the picture below

```
    function add_member_columns ( $columns ) {
    unset($columns['date']);
    return array_merge ( $columns, array (
        'contactperson'   => __ ( 'Contactpersoon' ),
        'phone_number'   => __ ( 'Telefoonnummer' ),
        'email'   => __ ( 'Email' ),
    ) );
}
add_filter ('manage_members_posts_columns', 'add_member_columns' );

function fill_member_columns ( $column, $post_id ) {
    switch ( $column ) {
        case 'contactperson':
            echo get_post_meta ( $post_id, 'contactperson', true );
            break;
        case 'phone_number':
            echo get_post_meta ( $post_id, 'phone_number', true );
            break;
        case 'email':
            echo get_post_meta ( $post_id, 'email', true );
            break;
    }
}
add_action ('manage_members_posts_custom_column', 'fill_member_columns', 10, 2 );
```

so this is what it looks like in the custom post type page
  [image: custom post type page]

In the advanced custom fields the first field is called company. 
how do i get it to be the title because it now just pics automatic concept as title?

Comment: You should probably start by making your CPT actually _support_ the standard title functionality, by specifying so in the `supports` array.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your array $args (in the code for making the custom post type) you see this line:

```
'supports' => array('')
```

In this array you can add all things to support. You can add title to it to make the titlefield appear, like this:

```
'supports' => array('title')
```

You can add multiple things to ' support' here, like editor and thumbnail. You can find a complete list and explanation about it in the [wordpress developer manual on registering post types](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/register_post_type/)

If you want to show an ACF field later in your template, you can add it the same way you did with contactpersoon, telefoonnummer etc.